# ValidationError: Token validation failed: user: Path `user` is required

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, postman, validationerror

I'm trying to create a user in a column and `sellerKeys` in another column. I'm getting:

> ValidationError: Token validation failed: user: Path `user` is required.

```
const createUser = async (userBody) => {
  if (await User.isEmailTaken(userBody.email)) {
    throw new ApiError(httpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, 'Email already taken');
  }
  // return User.create(userBody);
  const createdUser = await User.create(userBody);
  const sellerId = createdUser._id;
  const user = createdUser.name;
  console.log(user);

  const sellerkeyBody = {
    sellerId: sellerId, // Replace with the actual sellerId for the user
    user: user, 
    shopify: {
      isActive: false,
    erp: {
      isActive: false, 
    },
    magento: {
      isActive: false,
    },
    lazada: {
      isActive: false, 
    },
    shopee: {
      isActive: false, 
    }
    }
  };
  
  const createdSellerKey = await createSellerkey(sellerkeyBody);
 await createdUser.save();
 return { user: createdUser, sellerKey: createdSellerKey };
};
```

This is my code

Answer (score 0):

> ValidationError: Token validation failed: user: Path `user` is
> required.

This error often happens because you are missing a mandatory value (which must not be null). in this case you are trying to create a `sellerKeys` entity without giving your ORM a user object for the creation.